# Django datetime.date to timestamp converstion

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I am having problem getting some datetime conversions. I am actually using django and in one of model field I used `date` field not `datetime` field. Now I need to show time difference and I got the snippet for that from djangosnippets. But that accepts timestamp.

So I am confuse that what actually is python timestamp and how can it be made. I tried different things as in below lines:

```
publish_date.timetuple()
```

but this says, that `'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'mktime'`.I guess datetime.datetime has this mktime but not datetime.date so I can't use that.

```
int(parse(publish_date).strftime('%s'))
```

Here parse is from a third party module named dateutil but this time it gives following error.

```
datetime.date' object has no attribute 'read'
```

And it gives same error for following code:

```
humanizeTimeDiff(publish_date)
```

So any better idea or approach that I should try to convert datetime.date object to timestamp. It seems like converting datetime.datetime would be also helpful. But how ?

Comment: Since you are not storing the time (only the date), you can only show the difference in days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have any time information in your database (only date), you can only calculate the difference in number of days. To do that, simply subtract the date objects. This will yield a [`timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#available-types) which represents the difference between two date (or datetime) objects.

```
>>> d1
datetime.date(2012, 9, 16)
>>> d2
datetime.date(2012, 9, 17)
>>> d2-d1
datetime.timedelta(1)
>>> print d2-d1
1 day, 0:00:00
>>> print (d2-d1).days
1
```

Comment: In that case I guess I need to have current date also of type datetime.date , so how can I get that?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now().date()`

Comment: I was subtracting from current one thats why asked, however now have done getting current date by `date.today()` and then solved by getting idea from your solution that I was getting day only and time wasn't required so I changed my snippet to subtracting from `date.today()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` and my problem solved. thanks

Comment: @BurhanKhalid @Hafiz you can also just do `datetime.date.today()`

Comment: Thanks @JeffTratner I always forget about that one.

Comment: @JeffTratner yah I am using date.today() from datetime module